# Chrome Canary - Where's the feature list or changelog?

Tags: google-chrome

I understand what Canary is. But it's pretty useless if you don't know what beta features are available. So is there a place where this information can be found? I've been googling but can't find anything.

Answer (score 11):

Chrome Canary isn't the Chrome Beta, it's built daily and is the bleeding edge of Chromium development. Writing digested changelogs isn't feasible for daily builds.

You can have a look at every change here:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/

click on the current tag, e.g. `62.0.3168.0` and then on `log`.

For Chrome Beta, the Chromium Blog is a good resource:
https://blog.chromium.org/

e.g. for Chrome 60 Beta:
https://blog.chromium.org/2017/06/chrome-60-beta-paint-timing-api-css.html

Releases (Stable, Dev, Beta) in more detail:
https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/